# Read input every n seconds from device sending every m seconds using Go

Tags: go, serial-port

Using Go, I want to read every 1 second from a device connected to the serial port that sends a log terminated with a newline character every 300 ms. The fact that this is via the serial port should be immaterial, I believe. How can I read a new log entry every 1 second and dropping the other entries, since the device is writing log entries every 300 ms?

Comment: You can read every message and keep only the last one read in a goroutine. You can then have another goroutine that captures the current message read by the first goroutine every second.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the last time a log entry was processed.  Read log entries in a loop.  If time since log is greater than the desired frequency, process log and update last log time.

```
freq := time.Second
prev := time.Time{}
for {
    log := readLog()
    if time.Since(prev) > freq {
            prev = time.Now()
            // do something with log
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Go` channels to [rate-limit](https://gobyexample.com/rate-limiting) and throttle - and if you want to drop events, a buffered channel with `select` combined with `case default:` allows for non-blocking channel writes.

So, a simple polling implementation (similar to what [@BurakSerdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar) suggested - but instead messages are dropped until one is read - but yields the same result):

```
ch := make(chan string, 1) // 1 - so we keep at least one message
go func() {
    for {
        msg := getLog()
        
        // non-blocking write i.e. messages may be dropped
        select {
        case ch <- msg:
        default:
        }
    }
}()
```

and to read:

```
for msg := range ch {
    Info.Printf("throttled: %s", msg)
    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond) // throttle 1 message/s
}
```

Working example:

https://play.golang.org/p/_QIBGal4_jJ